# What is the significance of the expression $f(z_1,z_2) = \dfrac{z_1 - z_2}{1+ z_1 z_2 }$?

Tags: complex-numbers

Across a number of independent problem books involving complex numbers, I have seen the following function pop up

$$f(z_1,z_2) = \dfrac{z_1 - z_2}{1+ z_1 z_2 }$$

where $z_1, z_2 \in \mathbb{C}$ and $z_1z_2 \neq -1$.

It appears to have some nice properties, such as

> If $z_1$ and $z_2$ lie on the unit circle, then $\Re{\big (f(z_1,z_2)\big )}=0$

I am almost certain that the expression has some significance, otherwise I would not be seeing it across multiple independent sources. Unless it is some random conjured-up expression that just happens to have nice properties.

**Question:**
Is there any significance to this expression? Furthermore, is there any particular reason why it follows a similar structure to the familiar trigonometric identity? $$\tan(x-y) = \dfrac{\tan x - \tan y}{1+ \tan x \tan y}$$

Comment: Some *concrete* examples (where that function popped up and how it is used) would be constructive.

Comment: Are you sure that this is correctly reproduced, no overline or star is missing in the function definition?